Manga about a kid with a facial scar who was followed by the spirits of dead people
There was a story of a kid who had a big scar on his face and he always had some black spirits following him which were dead people whose smoke he absorbed as a child used in a experiment and he has like 500 of them in him

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Was this full colour or mostly black & white?

there was a manga with a child who had been experimented on , and now was a 'soul eater'. but the manga focused on the necromancer mc, not that sub character. there was a floating dungeon blocked by a flying skeleton, and a skeleton wyvern too ?
